# How to add an item to an array within context? (React typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I created a context search in my application, where I have an array called "searchPosts". My goal is to send an object from a component into this array in context and thus be able to use it in other components. I would like to create a global state where my object is stored

context

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export type SearchContextType = {
    searchPost: (text: string) => void;
};

export const SearchContext = createContext<SearchContextType>(null!);
```

provider

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SearchContext } from "./SearchContext"

export const SearchProvider = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
    const [searchPosts, setSearchPosts] = useState([]);

    const searchPost = (text: string) => {

    }

    return (
        <SearchContext.Provider value={{searchPost}}>
            { children }
        </SearchContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

I created this search function because in theory it should be a function for me to add the item to the array, but I don't know how I could do that.

This is the state that I have in my component called "searchPosts" that I get the object that I would like to pass to my global array. I want to pass the information from this array in this component to my global array in context

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const api = useApi();

  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [searchPost, setSearchPost] = useState([]);

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    const posts = await api.getAllPosts();
    const mapPosts = posts.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText));
    setSearchPost(mapPosts);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the component `searchPosts`, try to import `SearchContext` and import `searchPost` function from context component using `useContext` hook.

```
import {SearchContext} from './SearchContext'
const {searchPost} = useContext(SearchContext);;
```

Now, inside your `handleSearch` function, pass the `mapPosts` array to `searchPost` function that you imported from `useContext` hook, like this:

```
const handleSearch = async () => {
    const posts = await api.getAllPosts();
    const mapPosts = posts.filter(post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText));
    setSearchPost(mapPosts);
    searchPost(mapPosts);
  }
```

Now, inside your `searchPost` function inside your `provider` component, add following code:

```
const searchPost = (posts: any[]) => {
  setSearchPosts(prev => {
     return [...prev, ...posts];
  })
}
```

Comment: parameter) prev: never[]
Argument of type '(prev: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(prev: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(

Comment: in "prev => {" this error happens

Answer (score 0):

Add the `searchPost[]` to `SearchContextType`

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export type SearchContextType = {
  searchPost: (text: string) => void;
  searchResult: string[];
};

export const SearchContext = createContext<SearchContextType>(null!);
```

Create a reducer to manage your dispatch

```
//const SEARCH_POST = "SEARCH_POST"; in constants.ts
import { SEARCH_POST } from 'constants';
// reducer
export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SEARCH_POST: {
      return { ...state, searchResult: action.value };
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Create the provider

```
interface InitState {
  searchResult: string[];
}

export const SearchProvider = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  const initialState: InitState = {
    searchResult: [],
  };

  const [controller, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const value = useMemo(() => [controller, dispatch], [controller, dispatch]);

  return <SearchContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</SearchContext.Provider>;
};


export const searchPost = (dispatch, value) => dispatch({ type: SEARCH_POST, value });
```

Now create a custom hook to access the context

```
export const useSearchState = () => {
  const context = useContext(SearchContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      "useSearchState should be used inside the SearchProvider."
    );
  }

  return context;
};
```

In your component, you can use the above to access the state.

```
const [controller, dispatch] = useSearchState();
const {searchResult} = controller;

// to update the post you can call searchPost
// import it from search provider
searchPost(dispatch, posts)
```